# strange JSON return

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have an issue with JSON requests. I have a page with 2 different request,
first one works as intended, but the second keeps coming up with an unexpected token o error that I don't understand. 
first ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              url: 'inc/getloads.php?q='+boxnum,
              success:function(data){
                  if (data.l_id && data.u_id) {
                     var t_id = data.t_id;
                     var d_id = data.d_id;
                     var b_id  = data.b_id;
                     var bcont  = data.bcont;
                     var po_num = data.po_num;
                     var f_date = data.f_date;
                     var t_date  = data.t_date;
                     var depart  = data.depart;
                     var dest = data.dest;
                     var miles = data.miles;
                     var p_amt  = data.p_amt;
                     var tpm  = data.tpm;
                     var d_total = data.d_total;

                  }
```

This works just fine, all data is as they are supposed to, however here is the second call:

```
$.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              url: 'inc/getfunctions.php?q='+boxnum+'&func=load_po',
              success:function(data){
                    if (data.po_num) {
                     var e_id = data.l_id;
                     var load_num  = data.load_num;
                     var expense  = data.expense;
                     var ex_cost  = data.ex_cost;
                     var po_num  = data.po_num;

                  }
```

This one bombs with the unexpected tokens, I have read about not parsing it twice, is that a solution?
the php for the 2nd call:

```
$func = $_REQUEST['func'];
$_SESSION['func']= $func;
switch ($func) {
case 'load_po':
$q = intval($_REQUEST['q']);
require_once("medoo.min.php");
$database = new medoo();
$database->select("Expenses", "*", array(
"id" => $q));
if (count($datas)>0) {
    foreach($datas as $data){
        $l_id=$data['id'];
        $po_num=$data['po_num'];
        $load_num=$data['load_num'];
        $expense=$data['expense'];
        $ex_cost=$data['ex_cost'];
    }
    $rdata = array(
    'l_id'=> $l_id,
    'po_num'=> $po_num,
    'load_num'=> $load_num,
    'expense'=> $expense,
    'ex_cost'=> $ex_cost
    );
    echo json_encode($rdata); //$datas['first_name'] 
} else {
    echo 'no datas';
}
break;
}
```

Comment: Using `developers tools`, `network` tab -> you can investigate the output of the php file. Maybe it doesn't return what you're expecting it to return.

Comment: Can you post the JSON that blows up?

Comment: Start by encoding your data for use in a URL.

Comment: developers tools, network tab -> no datas

Comment: I figured out why im not getting back what i want, the no data pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

$datas is never initialized
and you have a foreach that can be executed multiple times, but you only assign the result once:

```
foreach($datas as $data){
  $l_id=$data['id'];
  $po_num=$data['po_num'];
  $load_num=$data['load_num'];
  $expense=$data['expense'];
  $ex_cost=$data['ex_cost'];
}
$rdata = array(
 'l_id'=> $l_id,
 'po_num'=> $po_num,
 'load_num'=> $load_num,
 'expense'=> $expense,
 'ex_cost'=> $ex_cost
);
```

so maybe if you only want to retrieve one row from *datas*, do something like:

```
$data = $datas[0];

$l_id=$data['id'];
$po_num=$data['po_num'];
$load_num=$data['load_num'];
$expense=$data['expense'];
$ex_cost=$data['ex_cost'];

$rdata = array(
  'l_id'=> $l_id,
  'po_num'=> $po_num,
  'load_num'=> $load_num,
  'expense'=> $expense,
  'ex_cost'=> $ex_cost
);
```